# How to position Fancybox based on element it was called From

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm am trying to figure out how to call Fancybox so that it appears next to the element (anchor tag) it was called from.

```
$("a.fancylink").fancybox({
    'width' : 560,
    'height' : 340,
    'transitionIn' : 'fade',
    'transitionOut' : 'fade',
    'speedIn' : 600, 
    'speedOut' : 200, 
    'overlayShow' : false,
    'centerOnScroll' : false
});
```

I know I can position the Fancybox with an OnComplete call, but then it jerks from the center to the destination.

Anyone know how to code the Fancybox call to make it open say left or right of the element it fired from?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work ok:

```
//pass in the id of the link that was clicked and set the width and height for the iframe   
$.fn.fancybox_new = function (options) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        options._id = $(this[i]).attr("id");
        $(this[i]).fancybox(options);
    }
};

$("a[rel*=fancybox]").fancybox_new({
    onStart: function () {
            $('#fancybox-wrap').addClass("formWin");
            //create a style that will position the fancy box relative to the element that clicked it.
            if (this._id != "" && !$(this).hasClass(this._id)) {
                var pos = $("#" + this._id).position();
                var mRight = parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("margin-right").replace("px").replace("auto", "0")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("padding-right").replace("px", "").replace("auto", "0")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("margin-left").replace("px", "").replace("auto", "0")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("padding-left").replace("px", "").replace("auto", "0"));
                var mTop = parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("margin-top").replace("px", "").replace("auto", "0")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("padding-top").replace("px", "").replace("auto", "0")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("margin-bottom").replace("px", "").replace("auto", "0")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("padding-bottom").replace("px", "").replace("auto", "0"));
                var styleTag = '<style type="text/css">.' + this._id + ' { top: ' + (pos.top + $("#" + this._id).height() + mTop) + 'px !important; right: ' + ($("#mainContainer").width() - pos.left - $("#" + this._id).width() - mRight + (($("body").width() - $("#mainContainer").width()) / 2)).toString() + 'px !important; left:auto !important; }</style>';
                $("head").append(styleTag);
                $('#fancybox-wrap').addClass(this._id);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you possibly explain this answer a bit more? I'm a jQuery rookie and it looks like the 2nd section is assigning a new onStart function to certain anchor links. When I change that to refer to a specific anchor link by id `$("#fb1")` I see the message "Object has no method 'fancybox_new'". How would I modify this code to be called from any javascript code to position the fancybox relative to an HTML element I specify?

Comment: The issue with positioning an individual fancy box is that it's difficult to get a reference to an individual fancy box that is usage by css since there is no id associated with it by default. The first section creates a light wrapper for the fancy box plugin constructor. The wrapper takes in the id on the **LINK** that the fancy box function is called on and passes and sets its one of the options.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved overriding this fancybox method:

```
$.fancybox.getViewport = function() { 
    // fancybox custom conditions for positioning here
    return {w: customWidht, h: customHeight, x: customLeft, y: customTop}
};
```

define `customWidht, customHeight, customLeft, customTop` to whatever suit your case, could be dynamic or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin i wrote to position elements. It has all kinds of positions, options.

You use it like so:

```
$("#Element").align($("#ParentElement"), {
    animate: false
});

// Align
// Author: Sam Striano
// Date  : 12/14/2010
jQuery.fn.align = function (parentElement, options, callback) {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Aligns an element over/around another element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parentElement" type="jQuery/String" optional="false">
    ///     Either a jQuery object or a selector string to align the selected element(s) on.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="options" type="Object" optional="true">
    ///     A set of key/value pairs that configure the alignment.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="callback" type="Function" optional="true">
    ///     A callback function that is executed once the alignment is complete.
    /// </param>
    var settings = jQuery.extend({
        animate: true,
        animateLength: 500,
        fadeIn: false,
        fadeInLength: 250,
        outerAlign: false,
        position: "MiddleCenter",
        show: true,
        hPadding: 0,
        vPadding: 0
    }, options),
        $parentElement = (typeof parentElement === "string") ? $(parentElement) : parentElement;

    return this.each(function () {
        // Cache Element
        var $element = $(this).css("position", "absolute"),
            x = 0,
            y = 0;

        // Calculate Position
        if (settings.outerAlign) {
            switch (settings.position) {
                case "TopLeft":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left - $element.outerWidth() - settings.hPadding);
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top - $element.outerHeight() - settings.vPadding);
                    break;
                case "TopCenter":
                    x = (($parentElement.offset().left + ($parentElement.outerWidth() / 2)) - ($element.outerWidth() / 2));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top - $element.outerHeight() - settings.vPadding);
                    break;
                case "TopRight":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + $parentElement.outerWidth() + settings.hPadding);
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top - $element.outerHeight() - settings.vPadding);
                    break;
                case "MiddleLeft":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left - $element.outerWidth() - settings.hPadding);
                    y = (($parentElement.offset().top + ($parentElement.outerHeight() / 2)) - ($element.outerHeight() / 2));
                    break;
                case "MiddleCenter":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + (($parentElement.outerWidth() / 2) - ($element.outerWidth() / 2)));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + (($parentElement.outerHeight() / 2) - ($element.outerHeight() / 2)));
                    break;
                case "MiddleRight":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + $parentElement.outerWidth() + settings.hPadding);
                    y = (($parentElement.offset().top + ($parentElement.outerHeight() / 2)) - ($element.outerHeight() / 2));
                    break;
                case "BottomLeft":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left - $element.outerWidth() - settings.hPadding);
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + $parentElement.outerHeight() + settings.vPadding);
                    break;
                case "BottomCenter":
                    x = (($parentElement.offset().left + ($parentElement.outerWidth() / 2)) - ($element.outerWidth() / 2));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + $parentElement.outerHeight() + settings.vPadding);
                    break;
                case "BottomRight":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + $parentElement.outerWidth() + settings.hPadding);
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + $parentElement.outerHeight() + settings.vPadding);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (settings.position) {
                case "TopLeft":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + settings.hPadding);
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + settings.vPadding);
                    break;
                case "TopCenter":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + (($parentElement.outerWidth() / 2) - ($element.outerWidth() / 2)));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + settings.vPadding);
                    break;
                case "TopRight":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + ($parentElement.outerWidth() - $element.outerWidth()) + (-settings.hPadding));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + settings.vPadding);
                    break;
                case "MiddleLeft":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + settings.hPadding);
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + (($parentElement.outerHeight() / 2) - ($element.outerHeight() / 2)));
                    break;
                case "MiddleCenter":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + (($parentElement.outerWidth() / 2) - ($element.outerWidth() / 2)));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + (($parentElement.outerHeight() / 2) - ($element.outerHeight() / 2)));
                    break;
                case "MiddleRight":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + ($parentElement.outerWidth() - $element.outerWidth()) + (-settings.hPadding));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + (($parentElement.outerHeight() / 2) - ($element.outerHeight() / 2)));
                    break;
                case "BottomLeft":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + settings.hPadding);
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + ($parentElement.outerHeight() - $element.outerHeight()) + (-settings.vPadding));
                    break;
                case "BottomCenter":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + (($parentElement.outerWidth() / 2) - ($element.outerWidth() / 2)));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + ($parentElement.outerHeight() - $element.outerHeight()) + (-settings.vPadding));
                    break;
                case "BottomRight":
                    x = ($parentElement.offset().left + ($parentElement.outerWidth() - $element.outerWidth()) + (-settings.hPadding));
                    y = ($parentElement.offset().top + ($parentElement.outerHeight() - $element.outerHeight()) + (-settings.vPadding));
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Position Element
        if (settings.animate) {
            if (callback) {
                $element.show().animate({ left: x, top: y }, settings.animateLength, callback(x, y));
            } else {
                $element.show().animate({ left: x, top: y }, settings.animateLength);
            }
        } else if (settings.fadeIn) {
            if (callback) {
                $element.hide().css({ left: x, top: y }).fadeIn(settings.fadeInLength, callback(x, y));
            } else {
                $element.hide().css({ left: x, top: y }).fadeIn(settings.fadeInLength);
            }
        } else {
            $element.css({ left: x , top: y });

            if (settings.show) {
                $element.show();
            }

            if (callback) {
                callback(x, y);
            }
        }

    });
};

// Center
// Author: Sam Striano
// Date  : 12/14/2010
jQuery.fn.center = function (parentElement) {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Centers an element over another element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parentElement" type="jQuery" optional="false">
    ///     The jQuery object to center the selected element(s) on.
    /// </param>
    var $element = $(this),
        $parentElement = (typeof parentElement === "string") ? $(parentElement) : parentElement;

    return this.each(function () {
        $element.align($parentElement, { animate: false, outsideAlign: false, position: "MiddleCenter" });
    });
};

// MakeSameSize
// Author: Sam Striano
// Date  : 12/14/2010
jQuery.fn.makeSameSize = function (parentElement) {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Makes the selected element(s) size the same as the parent element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parentElement" type="jQuery" optional="false">
    ///     The jQuery object.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="parentElement" type="String" optional="false">
    ///     The selector string of the parent element.
    /// </param>
    var $parentElement = (typeof parentElement === "string") ? $(parentElement) : parentElement;

    return this.each(function () {
        $(this)
            .css({
                height: $parentElement.innerHeight() + "px",
                width: $parentElement.innerWidth() + "px"
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: That's super complex, can you simplify so it directly answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to append #fancybox-wrap div to the desired parent div, and set the position in css.

The css^

```
#parent #fancybox-wrap {
left:0 !important;
top:0 !important;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#fancybox-wrap").appendTo("#parent");   

    jQuery('#parent').fancybox({    
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution for relative position:

```
$('.modal').fancybox({
    autoCenter: false,
    beforeShow: function() {
        var position = this.element.offset();
        $.fancybox._getPosition = function() {
            return position;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice and simple, I like that.

I've implimented your fix [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795727/fancybox-issues-swf-sizing-repostioning-fancybox-close-on-hover-out), but it's not working. Do you have any suggestions on what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: @AgentZebra Try to use .postion() instead .offset(). From jquery documentation:
_The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the document. When positioning a new element near another one and within the same containing DOM element, .position() is the more useful._